# Only notify when unreadable sectors increases

Tags: raid5, smart

Is there a way to only be notified when the amount of unreadable sectors increases on a certain disk?

```
The following warning/error was logged by the smartd daemon:
Device: /dev/sdb [SAT], 4 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
```

I have been getting this error for quite a while now in my mdadm RAID5 array and the amount of unreadable sectors does not increase. I am only planning to replace the disk when the unreadable sectors increase.

Comment: By then, it may be too late!

Answer (score 0):

Bad sectors mean disk issues.  Waiting for the sector count to increase simply doesn't make sense since by that threshold its already gone from 0 to 4, with the next potential jump being all.

Comment: Thats what we have RAID -  to have redundancy and not be affected by one HDD failing. So it is perfectly reasonable to wait until a disk fails completely, especially if a hot spare is already in.